# Additional options of a destination in the SAP HANA Cloud Platform cockpit

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

The item 9 of [this official guide](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?1e110da0ddd8453aaf5aed2485d84f25.html) says I can add and edit additional properties of the destination.

How can I know what allowed additional options and their allowed values are?

And what those options are for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the list of the additional properties and their possible values [HERE](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/SAP_RDE/frameset.htm?5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html), at the SAP HANA Cloud Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a documentation page with an exhaustive list of all potential additional destination properties. I would expect that additional properties are documented wherever they are needed.

For example, I found this page that documents [how to do ABAP RFC calls from HCP](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?0a238b915b3a48adb950e5807654226c.html). This page describes several `jco.client` properties that can be set in a destination with type `RFC`.